# Passing Data between View Controllers Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to iOS and Its developing.i have read Xcode old style passing data between view controllers.there i have seen lot of things going with xib files.please find below the code i have used to pass data in-between ViewControllers.but there in **customelink**(please find DetailViewController.m)there I'm getting Null value.please help me to get String value there.and kind enough to explain what are the mistakes I've done here.

EssentialInfoController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DetailViewController.h"
@interface Essentialinfocontroller : UIViewController
@end
```

EssentialInfoController.m

```
#import "Essentialinfocontroller.h"

@interface Essentialinfocontroller ()
@end

@implementation Essentialinfocontroller


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    DetailViewController * customelink= [DetailViewController alloc ];
    customelink.link=@"https://www.facebook.com";



}

@end
```

DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
@property(weak,nonatomic)NSString * link;

@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
 #import "DetailViewController.h"

    @interface DetailViewController ()

    @property(nonatomic,weak)NSString *customelink;
    @end

    @implementation DetailViewController
    @synthesize link;

    @synthesize customelink;


    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.customelink=self.link;


        NSLog(@"link--> %@",customelink);// here 2014-07-06 21:21:51.469 WADTourisum[880:60b] link--> (null)

    }

    @end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: What is this - DetailViewController * customelink= [DetailViewController alloc ]? 
You should never ever have an alloc without an init. But you probably don't want alloc init either depending on where you're making your view controllers. Are you using a storyboard?

Comment: @rdelmar yes I'm using story board

Comment: @nhgrif here i'm using story board.the previous one isnt based on story board.

Comment: You don't instantiate a storyboard view controller with alloc init, you use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.

Comment: Can you explain what you tried in the question I linked that didn't work?  There's code based on storyboard data transfers in that link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/2792531 Scroll down to **Passing Data Forward using Segue's**

Comment: @rdelmar he just logs to see the result in `detailVC`, so alloc init will be fine.

Comment: @PhamHoan, but I assume that he will want to see his view controller at some point, and alloc init will not work for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
DetailViewController * customelink= [DetailViewController alloc ];
```

should be

```
DetailViewController * customelink= [[DetailViewController alloc ] init];
```

and

```
@property(weak,nonatomic)NSString * link;
```

should be

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString * link;
```

and log it

```
NSLog(@"link--> %@",self.link);
```

you don't need this one

```
@property(nonatomic,weak)NSString *customelink;
```

---

if you use storyboard and segue then you have to implement
`-(void)prepareForSegue` method.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    }
}
```

assume that you got a `button` to move from `essentialVC` to `detailVC`, in you `IBAction`, call this method:

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE" sender:self];`

this is just a brief answer. I suggest you read about `UINavigationController` first, it's much easier to use compared to segue, IMHO.

Comment: im still faceing same issue 2014-07-06 21:50:25.290 WADTourisum[924:60b] link--> (null)

Comment: did you use storyboard ? because I don't see any code to move from `Essentialinfocontroller` to `DetailViewController`